# Código de barras en laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Tengo un error que no he podido solucionar. Tengo un punto de venta el cual, al realizar una venta el usuario, debe desplegar un `select` con los productos, lo cual esta bien. Pero necesito implementar un `input text` al cual poder ingresar un código de barras y así hacer la búsqueda mas rápida, pero al ingresar el código con la pistola este me genera un `enter`.

Lo que quiero es capturar el código antes del `enter` y enviarlo a una ruta, este a su vez a un controlador y el controlador me devuelva los datos del producto.

Adjunto mi código:

```
$("#codigobarra").change(function(event){ 
   $.get("barras/"+event.target.value+"".function(response){ 
      console.log(response); 
   }); 
});
```

Con eso trato de capturar el código y enviarlo a un controlador y así que devuelva los datos del producto.

```html
<form action="{{route('venta.store')}}" method="POST">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-8">  
      <label class="form-control-label" for="nombre">Nombre del Cliente</label>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
        @foreach($clientes as $client)
          <option value="{{$client->id}}">{{$client->nombre}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-8">  
      <label class="form-control-label" for="documento">Documento</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="tipo_identificacion" id="tipo_identificacion" required>
        <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
        <option value="FACTURA">Factura</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="num_vent">Cogigo de barras</label>
      <input type="text" id="codigobarra" name="codigo" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el codigo de barra">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="form-group row border">
    <div class="col-md-8">  
      <label class="form-control-label" for="nombre">Producto</label>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="id_producto" id="id_producto" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="0" selected>Seleccione</option>
        @foreach($productos as $prod)
          <option value="{{$prod->id}}_{{$prod->stock}}_{{$prod->precio_venta}}">{{$prod->producto}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
      <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control" value="1" pattern="[0-9]{0,15}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="stock">Stock</label>
      <input type="number" disabled id="stock" name="stock" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el stock" pattern="[0-9]{0,15}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="precio_venta">Precio Venta</label>
        <input type="number" disabled id="precio_venta" name="precio_venta" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese precio de venta" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="impuesto">Descuento</label>
        <input type="number" id="descuento" name="descuento" class="form-control" value="0" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" id="agregar" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i> Agregar detalle</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="form-group row border">
      <h3>Lista de Ventas a Clientes</h3>
      <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
        <table id="detalles" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr class="bg-success">
            <th>Eliminar</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Precio Venta ($)</th>
            <th>Descuento</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th>SubTotal ($)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <!--<th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th><h4 id="total">USD$ 0.00</h4><input type="hidden" name="total_venta" id="total_venta">  </th>-->
          <tr>
            <th  colspan="5"><p align="right">TOTAL:</p></th>
            <th><p align="right"><span id="total">$ 0.00</span> </p></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5"><p align="right">TOTAL IMPUESTO (20%):</p></th>
            <th><p align="right"><span id="total_impuesto">$ 0.00</span></p></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th  colspan="5"><p align="right">TOTAL PAGAR:</p></th>
            <th><p align="right"><span align="right" id="total_pagar_html">$ 0.00</span> <input type="hidden" name="total_pagar" id="total_pagar"></p></th>
          </tr>  
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer form-group row" id="guardar">
    <div class="col-md">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Registrar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
@push('scripts')
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#codigobarra").change(function(event){
      $.get("barras/"+event.target.value+"".function(response){
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
    $("#agregar").click(function(){
      agregar();
    });
  });

  var cont=0;
  total=0;
  subtotal=[];
  $("#guardar").hide();
  $("#id_producto").change(mostrarValores);
  function mostrarValores(){
    datosProducto = document.getElementById('id_producto').value.split('_');
    $("#precio_venta").val(datosProducto[2]);
    $("#stock").val(datosProducto[1]);
  }
  function agregar(){
    datosProducto = document.getElementById('id_producto').value.split('_');
    id_producto= datosProducto[0];
    producto= $("#id_producto option:selected").text();
    cantidad= $("#cantidad").val();
    descuento= $("#descuento").val();
    precio_venta= $("#precio_venta").val();
    stock= $("#stock").val();
    impuesto=0;
    if(id_producto !="" && cantidad!="" && cantidad>0  && descuento!="" && precio_venta!=""){
      if(parseInt(stock)>=parseInt(cantidad)){
        /*subtotal[cont]=(cantidad*precio_venta)-descuento;
        total= total+subtotal[cont];*/
        subtotal[cont]=(cantidad*precio_venta)-(cantidad*precio_venta*descuento/100);
        total= total+subtotal[cont];
        var fila= '<tr class="selected" id="fila'+cont+'"><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></button></td> <td><input type="hidden" name="id_producto[]" value="'+id_producto+'">'+producto+'</td> <td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" value="'+parseFloat(precio_venta).toFixed(2)+'"> </td> <td><input type="number" name="descuento[]" value="'+parseFloat(descuento).toFixed(2)+'"> </td> <td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"> </td> <td>$'+parseFloat(subtotal[cont]).toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>';
        cont++;
        limpiar();
        totales();
        /*$("#total").html("USD$ " + total.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_venta").val(total.toFixed(2));*/   
        evaluar();
        $('#detalles').append(fila);
      } else {
        //alert("La cantidad a vender supera el stock");
        Swal.fire({
          type: 'error',
          //title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'La cantidad a vender supera el stock',
        });
      }
    } else {
      //alert("Rellene todos los campos del detalle de la venta");
      Swal.fire({
        type: 'error',
        //title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'Rellene todos los campos del detalle de la venta',
      });
    }
  }
  function limpiar(){
    $("#cantidad").val("");
    $("#descuento").val("0");
    $("#precio_venta").val("");
  }
  function totales(){
    $("#total").html("USD$ " + total.toFixed(2));
    //$("#total_venta").val(total.toFixed(2));
    total_impuesto=total*impuesto/100;
    total_pagar=total+total_impuesto;
    $("#total_impuesto").html("USD$ " + total_impuesto.toFixed(2));
    $("#total_pagar_html").html("USD$ " + total_pagar.toFixed(2));
    $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar.toFixed(2));
  }
  function evaluar(){
    if(total>0){
      $("#guardar").show();
    } else {
      $("#guardar").hide();
    }
  }
  function eliminar(index){
    total=total-subtotal[index];
    total_impuesto= total*20/100;
    total_pagar_html = total /*+ total_impuesto*/;
    $("#total").html("USD$" + total);
    $("#total_impuesto").html("$" + total_impuesto);
    $("#total_pagar_html").html("$" + total_pagar_html);
    $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar_html.toFixed(2));
    $("#fila" + index).remove();
    evaluar();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: $("#codigobarra").change(function(event){
             $.get("barras/"+event.target.value+"".function(response){
            console.log(response);
            });
        
     });
con eso trato de capturar el codigo y enviarlo a un controlador y asi e devuelva los datos del producto

Comment: etiqueta la pregunta como jquery para que la vean los que entiende de eso, no hay nada de laravel en lo que preguntas

Comment: lo pudiste resolver? Por que estoy con el mismo problema